# export error when loading basic react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am learning react. but my basic sample is not working.
my app.js file is like below

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Greet } from './components/Greet';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="App"> 
    <Greet></Greet>
     </div>
  }
}
export default App;
```

my component file is like below

```
import React from 'react';
function Greet(){
    return <h1>Test</h1>
}
```

when i load my application, error said `Attempted import error: 'Greet' is not exported from './components/Greet'.` What is this error. how i fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) `Greet` function, so you couldn't import it in the `App.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
export function Greet(){
  return <h1>Test</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';

export function Greet(){
    return <h1>Test</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to export the Greet component.

Just add export before `function Greet()`:

```
import React from 'react';
export function Greet(){
     return <h1>Test</h1>
};
```